# Get caption numbers for the individual figure files

Tags: floats, captions, labels, subcaption

I would like to list the caption numbers for the figures of a latex document. My MWE is as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics{fig_alef.jpg}
\label{fig:fig_alef}
\caption{Alef.}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics{fig_bet.jpg}
\label{fig:fig_bet}
\caption{Bet.}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \begin{subfigure}[]{\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{fig_gimel.jpg}
    \label{fig:fig_gimel}
    \caption{Gimel.}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}[]{\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{fig_dalet.jpg}
    \label{fig:fig_dalet}
    \caption{Dalet.}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{Gimel + dalet.}
\end{figure}

\appendix
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{A\arabic{figure}}
\setcounter{figure}{0}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics{fig_he.jpg}
\label{fig:fig_he}
\caption{He.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The desired output is something like this:

```
\label{fig:fig_alef}: Figure 1
\label{fig:fig_bet}:  Figure 2
\label{fig:fig_gimel}: Figure 3 [perhaps with (a) - not so important]
\label{fig:fig_dalet}: Figure 3 [perhaps with (b) - not so important]
\label{fig:fig_he}: Figure A1
```

Can this correspondence between figure labels and caption numbers be extracted somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of what you want is done by `\listoffigures`.  You can control the content using the optional argument of `\caption`.  You can also modify `\l@figure` (which currently only calls `\@dottedtocline`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{duckuments}% remove ASAP

\captionsetup[subfigure]{list=true}

\begin{document}

\listoffigures
\newpage

\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics{example-image-a}
\label{fig:fig_alef}
\caption[\figurename~\thefigure]{Alef.}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics{example-image-b}
\label{fig:fig_bet}
\caption[\figurename~\thefigure]{Bet.}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \begin{subfigure}[]{\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-c}
    \label{fig:fig_gimel}
    \caption[\figurename~\thefigure\thesubfigure]{Gimel.}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}[]{\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
    \label{fig:fig_dalet}
    \caption[\figurename~\thefigure\thesubfigure]{Dalet.}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption[\figurename~\thefigure]{Gimel + dalet.}
\end{figure}

\appendix
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{A\arabic{figure}}
\setcounter{figure}{0}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics{example-image-duck}
\label{fig:fig_he}
\caption[\figurename~\thefigure]{He.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

---

This shows how to create a list of figures from scratch.  Note that the entries are in the same order as the `\modcaption`s.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{duckuments}% remove ASAP

\captionsetup[subfigure]{list=true}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\listofmodfigures}{\section*{List of Figures}\@starttoc{lom}}

\newcommand{\modcaption}[1]% #1 = content
  {\addcontentsline{lom}{modfigure}{\thefigure #1}}
  
\newcommand{\l@modfigure}[2]{\vskip \z@ \@plus.2\p@
  \noindent\parbox{\textwidth}{\leftskip=1.4em\relax
    \rightskip=\@pnumwidth
    \hskip-\leftskip\figurename~{#1}\leaders\hbox{$\m@th
      \mkern \@dotsep mu\hbox{.}\mkern \@dotsep mu$}\hfill\nobreak
    \rlap{\hb@xt@\@pnumwidth{\hfil\normalfont \normalcolor #2}}}%
  \par}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\listofmodfigures
\newpage

\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics{example-image-a}
\label{fig:fig_alef}
\caption{Alef.}\modcaption{}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics{example-image-b}
\label{fig:fig_bet}
\caption{Bet.}\modcaption{}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \begin{subfigure}[]{\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-c}
    \label{fig:fig_gimel}
    \caption{Gimel.}\modcaption{\thesubfigure}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}[]{\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
    \label{fig:fig_dalet}
    \caption{Dalet.}\modcaption{\thesubfigure}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{Gimel + dalet.}\modcaption{}
\end{figure}

\appendix
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{A\arabic{figure}}
\setcounter{figure}{0}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics{example-image-duck}
\label{fig:fig_he}
\caption{He.}\modcaption{}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image: demo2]

Comment: Witty solution, thank you. The only problem is that in some cases I also need a real list of figures within the document, so the `[]` argument of `caption`  is reserved. However, this solution could work with a modified `\modlistoffigures` command, which does the same as `listoffigures, but takes the text from elswhere. Do you have any idea how to do this?