# Map the figure filenames onto the figure numbers

Tags: macros, graphics, table-of-contents, captions, environments

I am in search of a way to form a map between figure filenames and their figure numbers. You can find an MWE below, where the desired output is specified.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{duckuments}

\begin{document}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Some code that provides the same output as the following fragment:
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

Figure map:
\begin{itemize}
\item Figure 1: example-image-a
\item Figure 2: example-image-b
\item Figure 3: example-image-c
\end{itemize}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics{example-image-a}
\label{fig:alef}
\caption[Alef figure.]{Alef.}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics{example-image-b}
\label{fig:bet}
\caption[Bet figure.]{Bet.}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics{example-image-c}
\label{fig:gimel}
\caption[Gimel figure.]{Gimel.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

A suboptimal solution is posted in answer to [Get caption numbers for the individual figure files](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/597416/get-caption-numbers-for-the-individual-figure-files/597433#597433), but sometimes I need to use `\listoffigures` to generate a real TOC by using the argument of `\caption`, [].

I thought of creating a replica of `\listoffigures`, but it seems that this is not feasible ([Modified command to obtain an alternative list of figures](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/597456/modified-command-to-obtain-an-alternative-list-of-figures/597482#597482)).

Comment: Do you need that the `itemize` list is filled automatically?

Comment: @egreg What is acceptable is to itemize, for example, the labels: \ref{fig:alef}, \ref{fig:bet}, \ref{fig:gimel}, then obtain the related filenames automatically. The more automated this process is, the better the solution is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In another thread ([How to sort a list indexed by figure numbers?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/597519/242407)) you asked for a more automated way to do this task.

Since you said it was a list to send to the publisher, I assume it's not the goal to have the text in the actual document. Therefore, I thought it was better to write off this data to an auxiliary file.

Add in your preamble

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}

% BEGIN Source:
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/597506/map-the-figure-filenames-onto-the-figure-numbers/597710?noredirect=1#comment1499574_597710

% BEGIN Optional
\usepackage{xstring}

\def\formatfigpathline#1#2{%
    \bgroup
    \def\frontpart{Figure #1:}%
    \StrLen{\frontpart}[\frontpartlength]%
    \ifnum\numexpr\frontpartlength\relax<11\relax
        \edef\frontpart{\frontpart\space\space\space\space}%
        \StrLeft{\frontpart}{11}[\frontpart]%
    \fi
    \xdef\figpathline{\frontpart\space #2}
    \egroup
}
% END

\makeatletter

\newcounter{fignumlength}

\ifx\formatfigpathline\@undefined
\def\formatfigpathline#1#2{%
    \def\figpathline{Figure #1: #2}%
}
\fi


\newwrite\figpathfile
\immediate\openout\figpathfile=\jobname_figures.txt\relax
\immediate\write\figpathfile{Version: \today}%

\def\figpath@stagedfigs{}
\def\figpath@stagefig#1{%
    \expandafter\gdef\expandafter\figpath@stagedfigs\expandafter{%
        \figpath@stagedfigs\do{#1}%
    }%
}

\newbool{FigpathIsEnabled}
\newbool{FigpathEnableOnIncludegraphics}
\setbool{FigpathEnableOnIncludegraphics}{true}

\newcommand\figpathEnable{%
    \unless\ifx\label\@figpathLabel
        \global\let\orig@label\label
        \let\label\@figpathLabel
    \fi
    \unless\ifFigpathIsEnabled
        \global\booltrue{FigpathIsEnabled}%
    \fi
}

\newcommand\figpathDiscard{%
    \gdef\figpath@stagedfigs{}%
}

\newcommand\figpathDisable{%
    \ifx\label\@figpathLabel
        \let\label\orig@label
    \fi
    \ifFigpathIsEnabled
        \figpathDiscard
        \global\boolfalse{FigpathIsEnabled}%
    \fi
}

\newbool{@figpath@isfigure}

\newcommand\figpathFlush{%
    \boolfalse{@figpath@isfigure}
    \def\@cntr@name@figure{figure}%
    \def\@cntr@name@subfigure{subfigure}%
    \ifx\@currentcounter\@cntr@name@figure
        \@figpath@isfiguretrue
    \fi
    \ifx\@currentcounter\@cntr@name@subfigure
        \@figpath@isfiguretrue
    \fi
    \if@figpath@isfigure
        \bgroup\def\do##1{%
            \formatfigpathline{\@currentlabel}{##1}%
            \immediate\write\figpathfile{\figpathline}%
        }%
        \figpath@stagedfigs\gdef\figpath@stagedfigs{}%
        \egroup
    \else
        \PackageWarning{figpath}{Not flushing figure paths: wrong counter (\@currentcounter)!}%
    \fi
}

\AtBeginDocument{
    \newcommand\@figpathIncludegraphics[2][]{%
        \ifFigpathEnableOnIncludegraphics
            \unless\ifFigpathIsEnabled
                \figpathEnable
                \aftergroup\figpathDisable
            \fi
        \fi
        \ifFigpathIsEnabled
            \figpath@stagefig{#2}%
        \fi
        %
        \orig@includegraphics[#1]{#2}%
    }
    \global\let\orig@includegraphics\includegraphics
    \global\let\includegraphics\@figpathIncludegraphics

    \let\orig@label\label
    \let\label\@figpathLabel
}

\def\@figpathLabel{%
    \ifFigpathIsEnabled
        \figpathFlush
    \fi
    \orig@label
}

\makeatother

\AtEndEnvironment{figure}{
    \figpathFlush
}
\AtEndEnvironment{subfigure}{
    \figpathFlush
}

\AtBeginEnvironment{figure}{
    \figpathDiscard
    \figpathEnable
}
\AtEndEnvironment{figure}{
    \figpathDisable
}
% END
```

and use your figures and subfigures just like normal.

This creates a file containing

```
Figure 1: example-image-a
Figure 2a: example-image-b
Figure 2b: example-image-c
```

If your document is called `document.tex`, the file is called `document_figures.txt`, i.e. `_figures.txt` is appended after it.

Is this what you wanted?

Comment: One caviat: if you caption a figure without assigning a label, it won't appear in the list. You could solve this by triggering the `\writecurrfig` after a `\caption` instead of after a `\label`, but this requires a bit more modification

Comment: Thank you, Vincent, wonderful solution! It is really practical to have this list in a separate file. It is not a problem to move \label{} before caption. It is also fantastic that your solution works for non-float figures whose caption is specified by \captionof{}.

Comment: Glad you like it! And just to avoid confusion: `\label` should always be after the `\caption`. What I was after is that after `\caption` is executed, the `\@currentname` is available, so anywhere after that point `\writecurrfig` can be executed. If I hook it to `\caption`, it's just that I need to take in the arguments for him, because the `\writecurrfig` needs to be executed afterwards. `\label` is then a slightly cleaner hook, if you always use it

Comment: Yes, most journals require that figures should be cited within the manuscript, so a label is always part of all my figures.

Comment: I encountered a minor issue while running your solution: if there are two `includegraphics` within the same figure block (e.g., I call `\includegraphics{example-image-a}` twice one after another), then  I receive an error: `TeX capacity exceeded, sorry`. In this case, it would be useful to list all the figure paths with the same figure number. Is this a solvable problem?

Comment: @TobiR I've updated my answer to allow for that!

Comment: @TobiR But it makes me think about further improvements. For example, if you now use `\includegraphics`, but don't assign a label (for example, it is a logo on your page, or decoration), it will still be stored on the list of paths. So next time you `\label` an actual figure, it will appear in the list too.

Comment: @TobiR It's easy for me to add some safety measures, but then I need to know how flexible you want things. I mean, I could make this feature only work with `figure` environments for example. And then I could open up things a bit more, for example when using subfigs, they could receive the enclosing figure's figure number if you don't caption it on it's own. What do you want?

Comment: Btw, you could swap `\jobname.fpa` for any other name you like, like for examples `figures.txt`. I was just following the convention of other aux files here, but I guess a txt extension and a clear name could work better for you

Comment: Vincent, thanks for your update. Now works for repeated includegraphics excellently. As to your question regarding further constraints, I would treat both float and non-float figures with your code, so it should work for both cases. Your idea about the enclosing figure numbers sounds good, so I would be happy if you included it in your post.

Comment: @TobiR And with non-float figures you mean still `figure` environment (just `H` option as provided by floats package)? Or do you mean your own wrapper using minipages?

Comment: No, I do not use wrappers with minipages, but I often use `\begin{center}\includegraphics{...}\captionof{figure}{...}\end{center}` to specify a figure. I suspect that this construction corresponds to a `figure` environment due to `\captionof{figure}`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124549/discussion-between-vincent-kuhlmann-and-tobir).

Comment: @TobiR So to mention it outside chat, for anyone coming down here: the code has been updated to include more safeguards against erroneous entries, as well as better handling if a `\label` is forgotten

Comment: Vincent, thank you for all these actions. Unfortunately, compiling this version throws errors complaining about `\@currentcounter`.

Comment: @TobiR I tested for figures, subfigure, and centered like you used. In which setup did you encounter this error? But yeah, my safeguards are all not very essential. My version before this can safely be used. Still, don't think it's difficult to fix this, and obtain some polished code

Comment: I see errors for all the `label` lines: https://www.overleaf.com/4153935556swftvsbgsspq.

Comment: @TobiR apparently, the definition of `\@currentcounter` is present in my installation, but not in Overleaf's. I've replaced it manually now. Everything works :)

Comment: Oh, sorry for the inconvenience. :( And most importantly, thanks for all your effort to solve this problem.

Comment: @TobiR Don't worry about me putting out these efforts. I learn a lot from them! That's what making it great fun. And if I can help someone in doing so, it's double fun haha :)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a possible way. Note that the `\label` should go *after* the caption.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\RFincludegraphics}[2][]{% RF for `remember file'
  \def\@currentimage{#2}%
  \includegraphics[#1]{#2}%
}
\newcommand{\RFlabel}[1]{%
  \label{#1}\let\@currentlabel\@currentimage\label{RF@#1}%
}
\newcommand{\fileref}[1]{%
  \ref{#1}: \texttt{\ref{RF@#1}}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Some code that provides the same output as the following fragment:
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

Figure map:
\begin{itemize}
\item Figure \fileref{fig:alef}
\item Figure \fileref{fig:bet}
\item Figure \fileref{fig:gimel}
\end{itemize}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{figure}[htp]
\centering
\RFincludegraphics{example-image-a}
\caption[Alef figure.]{Alef.}
\RFlabel{fig:alef}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[htp]
\centering
\RFincludegraphics{example-image-b}
\caption[Bet figure.]{Bet.}
\RFlabel{fig:bet}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[htp]
\centering
\RFincludegraphics{example-image-c}
\caption[Gimel figure.]{Gimel.}
\RFlabel{fig:gimel}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I like this solution very much! Simple, practical, and elegant. Thank you for posting this answer.

Comment: The only problem is that this list is not ordered by the figure numbers. Do you have a trick to order the itemized list?

Comment: @TobiR What do you mean? It seems ordered to me.

Comment: Yes, because you listed the figure labels in ascending order by their numbers. But if you swap the first two items (`\item Figure \fileref{fig:alef}` and `\item Figure \fileref{fig:bet}`), then the list becomes unordered. So sorting the items would also be practical. However, in this case subfigure numbers (e.g., Figure 2a) could cause additional issues.