# How to sort a list indexed by figure numbers?

Tags: enumerate, itemize, enumitem, sorting, includegraphics

I would like to sort a list indexed with figure references by the item numbers. My MWE is the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{duckuments}

\captionsetup[subfigure]{list=true}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
    \item[\ref{fig:gimel}.] gimel
    \item[\ref{fig:alef}.] alef
    \item[\ref{fig:bet}.] bet
\end{itemize}

% Desired output:
% 1. alef
% 2a. bet
% 2b. gimel

\begin{figure}[b]
\centering
\includegraphics{example-image-a}
\caption{Alef.}
\label{fig:alef}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \begin{subfigure}[]{\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-b}
    \caption{Bet.}
    \label{fig:bet}
    \end{subfigure}
    
    \begin{subfigure}[]{\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-c}
    \caption{Gimel.}
    \label{fig:gimel}
    \end{subfigure}
    
    \caption{Double figure.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Is there any trick to perform this sort automatically?

Comment: And just to make sure: \listoffigures is not satisfactory?

Comment: @VincentKuhlmann Unfortunately, I need `\listoffigures` to construct real TOCs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to see whether `\listoffigures` is what you wanted, but I've made precisely what you asked for. In the preamble add

```
\makeatletter

% We store all the labels in a list
\def\orderedlabels{}
\def\addorderedlabel#1{%
    \expandafter\gdef\expandafter\orderedlabels\expandafter{\orderedlabels\do{#1}}%
}

% Hook on aux label entries
\let\orig@newl@bel\@newl@bel
\def\@newl@bel#1#2#3{%
    \addorderedlabel{#2}%
    \orig@newl@bel{#1}{#2}{#3}%
}

% For debugging
\def\rawprintorderedlabels{%
    \def\do##1{(##1),}%
    \orderedlabels
}

% Provide appearance of label item
\def\providelabelitem#1#2{%
    \expandafter\def\csname orderedlabel@#1\endcsname{#2}%
}

% Use appearance of label item
\def\placelabelitems{%
    \def\do##1{%
        \csname orderedlabel@##1\endcsname
        \expandafter\let\csname orderedlabel@##1\endcsname\relax
    }%
    \orderedlabels
}

\makeatother
```

and in your document use

```
\providelabelitem{fig:gimel}{
    \item[\ref{fig:gimel}.] gimel
}
\providelabelitem{fig:alef}{
    \item[\ref{fig:alef}.] alef
}
\providelabelitem{fig:bet}{
    \item[\ref{fig:bet}.] bet
}

\begin{itemize}
    \placelabelitems
\end{itemize}
```

What is going on here?

- I added a hook into the `.aux` file's `\newlabel` command. The `.aux` file gets executed right before the document starts.
- The `\newlabel` command now additionally adds the labels to a list, which I called `\orderedlabels`
- In your document (or preamble is fine too) you use `\providelabelitem` for all the labels you want to see used in your list.
- Next, you call `\placelabelitems`, which goes through the list of labels just created, and for each item, if you have provided something for the corresponding label, those provided contents are placed.

So note if you specify a label which doesn't end up being used, it won't appear in the list either, and neither do you get any warning or error if you don't include all the figures in your list.

You can use `\placelabelitems` multiple times, and I've set contents to be erased after use. So after using `\placelabelitems`, only for what you use `\providelabelitems` will be included in the next `\placelabelitems`; no leaks.

Does this do what you wanted? :)

---

### More automation

1. And if all you want is just simple `\item`'s like in your example, then you can additionally add in your preamble

   ```
   \newcommand\providelabelname[2]{
       \providelabelitem{#1}{
           \item[\ref{#1}.] #2
       }
   }
   ```

   And simply use

   ```
   \begin{itemize}
       \providelabelname{fig:gimel}{gimel}
       \providelabelname{fig:alef}{alef}
       \providelabelname{fig:bet}{bet}
       \placelabelitems
   \end{itemize}
   ```

   in your document.
2. Even more automation: if you want to have the text be just the fig labels, like in your MWE, add `\usepackage{xstring}` and this command

   ```
   \newcommand\provideallfigures{%
       \def\do##1{%
           \IfBeginWith{##1}{fig:}{%
               \providelabelname{##1}{\StrGobbleLeft{##1}{4}\relax}%
           }{}%
       }%
       \orderedlabels
   }
   ```

   Then you can do

   ```
   \begin{itemize}
       \provideallfigures
       \placelabelitems
   \end{itemize}
   ```

Comment: Thank you for posting all three versions. My original goal (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/597506/) is close to what you provided after "EDIT": a list of figure numbers and **the associated figure filenames**. 
To adapt the MWE to this problem, I would expect an output: (Fig. 1, example-image-a), (Fig. 2a, example-image-b), (Fig. 2b, example-image-c).

This list would be useful to submit figures to certain journals who want me to specify the figure numbers for the individual figure files. Do you have a trick to generate such a list?

Comment: @TobiR I have a solution for you. But I feel the answer is already very long and it would just be beneficial if you opened a new question instead. Also for if other people search for this...

Comment: OK, I can create a new question and put its link here, but it would be a solution to post a new answer under tex.stackexchange.com/questions/597506. I think that the question remains the same. What do you think?

Comment: @TobiR ok sure, will post it there

Comment: Thank you very much!